# How to imitate the native iPhone look and feel in a web app developed with the ASP.NET platform?

Tags: iphone, css, web-applications

I'm planning to develop a web application that targets the iPhone. I will use APT.NET to develop the application. I will probably use ASP.NET MVC.

I'm researching how I will imitate the native iPhone look and feel in my web application. I'm looking for an approach that will be easy to use with the ASP.NET platform.

So far, I found iUI (code.google.com/p/iui/). iUI a collection of CSS stylesheets and javascripts to imitate the native iPhone look and feel. I'm not sure yet how easy it is to integrate with ASP.NET as most samples are static html.

What are good ways to imitate the native iPhone look and feel in a web app developed with the ASP.NET platform?

Regards,

Syl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these:

1. [Rock the iPhone with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2008/06/08/rock-the-iphone-with-aspnet-mvc/)
2. [Create iPhone Applications using ASP.NET AJAX](http://steveorr.net/articles/iPhone.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Robert, I had already seen the first one, it is about iUI. That is the one I mentioned in my question. The second post does not seem to be about imitating the native iphone look and feel.

Comment: I figured you had the UI already. I thought both of these would give you a start in the code and solution layout.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to let you know that I also found http://iwebkit.net/. I will test it in the upcoming days.

If you have other suggestions, I will greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server-side platform you use is irrelevant to the front-end look and feel, it is the same techniques on any platform.

I have also used the iUI framework with great success, using a Django backend. The front-end is determined purely by the HTML, CSS and JavaScript that you serve up, which is independant of the server-side code.

ASP.NET MVC gives you a lot more control over your markup than plain-old WebForms, so it should be ideal for this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience with iUI, I really appreciate. I agree that this is *mostly* a front-end issue. However, as you can see in the first link posted by Robert Kozak, the author explains that the way iUI works forces you into a specific way of returning page content (back-end issue). For this reason, if I choose iUI, I might *have to* use MVC because I'm not sure standard ASP.NET will let me generate the partial page content that is required.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. You're probably right that WebForms out of the box will not provide what you need, but then WebForms out of the box is hideous and should be avoided with a very big barge pole! Unless you have a specific requirement not to, I would recommend MVC over WebForms on most applications these days (thats not to say it always makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP. I'm updating this question with a new answer:

- [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)